# 2 Threads to execute 2 similar jobs

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 jobs I want to execute in JAVA. I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   takeInfofromDB();
   doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData();

   takeInfofromDB2();
   doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData2();

   GenerateAnswerFromBothAnswers();
}
```

Is it possible to somehow put `takeInfofromDB();` and `doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData();` in 2 Threads? And `GenerateAnswerFromBothAnswers();` can't execute while at least one is still working?

Comment: Of course it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: @JBNizet I tried creating 2 separate classes, but I don't want 2 separate classes. Also, can't get `GenerateAnswerFromBothAnswers();` work only when 2 threads are finished

Comment: Show us your code, so that we can help you fixing and improving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           takeInfofromDB(); 
           doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData();
       }});

   Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         takeInfofromDB2();
         doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData2();
       }});

   t1.start();
   t2.start();

   t1.join();
   t2.join();

   GenerateAnswerFromBothAnswers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple lightweight approach, try the following code.  However you may want to read more about Threads and eventually Executors: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
    private Object result;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        takeInfofromDB();
        result = doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData();
    }

    public Object getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
    private Object result;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        takeInfofromDB2();
        result = doSomeLongCalculationsWithThatData2();
    }

    public Object getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread1.join();
thread2.join();

Object result1 = thread1.getResult();
Object result2 = thread2.getResult();

GenerateAnswerFromBothAnswers(result1, result2);
```

You shouldn't run this code as is (I haven't tested it, and weird things could happen if you call `getResult` before `join`), but it should serve as a starting point for how to use threads in a basic way.